# Laravel 9: Email links are changing

Tags: laravel, email

After upgrading to Laravel 9, all the emails that are sent from my application contain broken links (instead of the correct link) in Gmail (and also Yahoo mail). Basically, the value of the `href` attribute in my email views is replaced by a broken link:

`https://email.mail.mydomain.io/c/eJxNjksKwyAURVejsxY_-ZiBg0DJAroDfe-ZWJIYjC1093VSWrijw7mXi9ZJcjxa8OD7VptBUStV32NwEgVqYzqgBgNrRMkOV8rXmPhifQAUCrAbTOeVwSYEGVpQyvsKheerXUo5TqZHpqaab_u3UuEcX3TJBGneY4lpr_p0PrfN5TfTtzsBVQF5tg93HpT_TkD6AIjKPZE`

Here is my email view:

```php
@extends('layouts.mail')

@section('title')
    {{ $subject }}
@endsection

@section('body')
    <img src="{{ tenant_config('logo_path') ?? global_asset("/img/logo/logo.png") }}" alt="{{ tenant_config('company_name') }}" class="logo" style="display:block;max-width:300px;margin-top:.5rem;margin-bottom:30px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;" >

    <h1 class="text--blue" style="text-align:center;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:1rem;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;font-size:2.4rem;color:#3bafbf;" >
        +{{ $hit->reward }}<span class="text--pts">{{ __('global.pts') }}</span>
    </h1>

    <p style="text-align:center;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:1rem;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;" >
        {{ __('mails/notification.there_is_time', ['name' => $hit->user->firstname]) }}
    </p>

    <p style="text-align:center;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:1rem;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;" >
        {{ __('mails/notification.dont_reply') }}
    </p>

    <p style="text-align:center;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:1rem;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;" >
        <a href="{{ $actionUrl }}" class="button" style="background-color:#3bafbf;text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff;padding-top:.75rem;padding-bottom:.75rem;padding-right:1.5rem;padding-left:1.5rem;transition:box-shadow 150ms ease-in-out;display:inline-block;margin-top:5px;border-radius:4px;box-shadow:0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);font-size:1.5rem;" >{{ __('mails/global.visit_my_profile') }}</a><br>
    </p>
@endsection
```

How can this be fixed?
I have also been using the `archtechx/tenancy` package for multi-tenancy.

Comment: That looks like your email service provider is converting links to some sort of tracking link to track clickthroughs. Which email driver are you using? If you do `curl -I https://email.mail.mydomain.io/c/eJxNjk...`, does it show a redirect via a `Location` header to somewhere? How is `$actionUrl` generated?

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm using mailgun. The `curl -I` command returns an `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed` response from an `nginx` server. The `$actionUrl` is generated in my Mail class and shows correctly everywhere except for the `href` attribute.

Comment: Do you get the `405` error when visiting the link in the browser? What does happen when you do?

Comment: @ceejayoz Chrome tells me there's an invalid certificate: `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

Comment: Thank you @ceejayoz, my issue is fixed! I had to set the tracking protocol in Mailgun from `http` to `https` and that did the trick!

Comment: Glad that pointed you in the right direction. :-)

Comment: FYI: You can apparently make Mailgun's tracking inks work with SSL with a bit of work. https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011566033-How-to-Enable-HTTPS-Tracking-Links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. My email service provider (Mailgun) is replacing my email links with  tracking links to track clicks. I just had to set the tracking protocol in Mailgun from `http` to `https`, which fixed it.